# Magento - Hiding sold products in inner search engine, but NOT hiding them on Google searches

Tags: php, magento, search-engine

I'm a total n00b at Magento, and I need to hide sold products from the inner (i.e. Magento's built-in) search engine. BUT I don't want to hide them regarding Google searches.

This means: the url for the product should still be indexable by Google, but should not be returned by the Magento inner / in-site search.

**Question**: Is there a way to filter the Magento search engine, so the already-sold products are not returned?

Comment: FYI, Magento has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK I move the question there...

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set the product to not visible individually in the general tab.

Go to Catalog>Manage Products>  Go to the product that you do not want visible.

Go to the General Tab.  Then there is the Visibility option.  Set that to Not Visible Individually and that will correct your issue.

What do you mean by sold products? If this does not solve your problem.

Comment: If you use this option, you wont be able to access the product at it's own URL (the OP requires this) - it will need to be part of a bundle/configurable product instead.